# Office 365 api (or equivalent) for Word/Excel collaborative editing without account?

Tags: office365, collaboration, office365api, richtextediting

Is there a way to create/edit Word/Excel documents using an API, and then allow users to edit them without needing an Office 365 account (using some url based token) ?

My website already give the possibility for users to upload documents, and I would like to add on my website the possibility for users to create documents (word processor and spreadsheet), and give them the possibility to edit them online (like on Office 365).

Is there a way to achieve this with Office 365 API? Or maybe some kind of "offline" API (where all the files are stored on my website)? Or maybe some Open source tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to add on my website the possibility for users to create documents (word processor and spreadsheet)

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153916/office-365-create-docx-pptx-xlsx-files)  : There is no API currently to create a new file of a particular type, you could firstly upload different kinds of empty file(Word, Excel, PowerPoint) as templates, and then you can create any kinds of documents by copying the template to another file via Microsoft Graph api . Graph API provides copy method to copy an existing file to another: [Copy a driveItem to a new location](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_copy).

To edit the  file online .You could [create a sharing link](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink) for the file using microsoft graph api . You could choose the scope to make the item accessible to anyone or inside your organization ,make type to edit ,that will create a read-write link to the item with office online . Or you could firstly access and download your file with rest api , edit the local file and upload to onedrive/sharepoint again .

Comment: Is this answer still true in year 2023? Is there no Open free to use API for this to achieve?